# Java Applet: setForeground() what exactly it does? and how to see it's effect?

Tags: java, applet

As per "Java - The Complete Reference Java" `setForeground()` is used to set the foreground colour i.e the colour in which text is shown.

Now consider this basic applet program that sets the foreground and background colours and outputs a string:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

/*
< applet code="Sample" width=1000 height=500>
< /applet>
*/

public class Sample extends Applet
{
    String msg;
    // set the foreground and background colors.

    public void init() 
    {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setForeground(Color.red);
        msg = "Inside init( ) --";
    }

    // Initialize the string to be displayed.
    public void start()
    {
        msg += " Inside start( ) --";
    }

    // Display msg in applet window.
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
      msg += " Inside paint( ).";
      g.drawString(msg, 10, 30);
    }
}
```

`The background colour can be changed to any colour by setBackground()` BUT **no matter what colour given inside setForegorund() the text is always black!!!** i.e it does not change the text colour at all. Then what is the function/use of `setForegorund()` , and how can I see the effect of it?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, as I have already mentioned, setBackground() works with any colour.

Comment: As you are overriding paint(), consider setting the color in the paint method : g.setColor(Color.RED);

Comment: What is the problem when giving the Graphics object a color ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant setForground() yes, yes g.setColor(Color.red); works but my question is effect of setForeground(). Thank you

Comment: setForeground is called on a component : a Panel, a TextField, a Button, etc.. .  This is meant to set a foreground color used by the default paint method of the Component .As long as you override paint, I believe you can't trust this call, you are responsible for setting all parameters of the Graphics object. However, try to call super.paint at the beginning of your paint method, as it should call the default paint method of your applet first, and probably set the color of the Graphics object to your foreground color..

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but it gives error: error: no suitable method found for paint() super.paint();

Comment: Sorry, I meant super.paint(g);

Comment: I tried super.paint(g); no error but still no change to text color :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it has no effect unless your code makes use of the method `getForeground()`.

Swing, built on top of AWT, makes use of it when it calls [`getComponentGraphics()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/swing/JComponent.java#JComponent.getComponentGraphics%28java.awt.Graphics%29) - a protected method of `JComponent` it uses in its `paint()` method where it paints component borders etc. But AWT itself doesn't have any internal use for the foreground color, and doesn't use it by default for painting.

You can use it by using `graphics.setColor(getForeground())` if you wish.

Comment: Thank you so much It worked, As you said setColor(getForeground()) inside paint() makes use of setForeground(Color.x) and changes the colour of text to x defined inside init() :)